# Google Maps - Markers drifting by 100's miles upon Zoom

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Simplified version of my Maps app here (dummy map data from google spreadsheet via JSON):

http://jsfiddle.net/mpAKk/

I am noticing that markers on the map will drift 100's of miles from their intended locations when zooming out in range of level 6 thru 4 and beyond.  I had not noticed this effect before on prior map projects.

Normal, or something am doing wrong?

Example: Notice the RED marker in Minnesota (at the initial zoom 4).  It really belongs in Ashland, Wisconsin.  When you zoom-in past level 6, it seems to locate more accurately.

```
Any ideas/suggestions?
```

Thanks!

Mark

Comment: I clicked on 6 markers. 5 were not even close to where they should be. This is at the default zoom level.

Comment: Yes, the mailing address info is bogus for this POC test app.  You can ignore.

The point of the question is the drifting markers themselves.

Comment: I don't see any markers on that jsfiddle.  Sounds like a problem with the custom icons anchor.

Comment: geocodezip - you see no markers on that map?  There are 100 of them in my view.

Comment: Nope, no markers.  Unless they take a _really_ long time to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iconHotSpotOffset has to be `new google.maps.Point(6,20)`   , not `(9,34)`
[image]

However, MarkerImage is deprecated, you should use an [**Icon**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#ComplexIcons) instead.

Comment: Yes!  This corrects my issue.  I suspect I lifted that line of code from somewhere else.  Never tweaked the parameters. - Thanks!